How to print a number using commas as hundred separators using python?
num=987756
...
#output 98,77,56
num=20787
.....
#output 2,07,87
how can i get it ??
can python format function thousand separator to hundred separator  ?
my code below ,anyone can another methode like as "{:,}".format
num=85300
sep=2 # 2=100 3=1000
j,m,n=1,[],""
for i in str(num)[::-1]:
    n=i+n
    if j==sep:        
        m.insert(0,n)
        n,j="",0
    j+=1
else:
    if n:
        m.insert(0,n)       
    print(",".join(m))

#output:-8,53,58
num=85241
sep=2
Dse=10**sep
z=[]
while num>0:
    z.insert(0,num%Dse)
    num=num//Dse
else:
    print(z)

#it's value based sep to list

It's not clear to me why you want to do this, because I'm not aware of any cultures that normally represent numbers this way. Indian is close, but they use three digits in the last group, and two digits in groups above that.

Using babel (pip install babel):
>>> from babel.numbers import format_decimal
>>> format_decimal(987756, "#,##")
'98,77,56'
>>> format_decimal(20787, "#,##")
'2,07,87'


You can convert it to string, then just add comma for every 2 steps:
def _format_number(num, sep=2):
    num_str = str(num)[::-1]
    parts = [num_str[i:i + sep] for i in range(0, len(num_str), sep)]
    formatted = ",".join(parts)[::-1]
    return formatted


nums = [987756, 20787, 85358, 10381083, 134701273]
for num in nums:
    print(_format_number(num))
    print(_format_number(num, 3))


Prints
98,77,56
987,756
2,07,87
20,787
8,53,58
85,358
10,38,10,83
10,381,083
1,34,70,12,73
134,701,273


